# How to force an NPM package to use dependencies from its own node_modules folder?

Tags: npm, eslint, create-react-app, yarnpkg, react-scripts

Recently I have updated the version of ESLint 5.16.0 -> 7.5.0 (I know neither of them is the most recent version but bear with me).

The project itself utilizes yarn workspaces and was bootstrapped by CRA and therefore uses `react-scripts` as one of its dependencies, which in turn has its own `node_modules` folder and `package.json` where the required version of `eslint` is "^5.16.0".

[image: react-scripts-package.json]

However, since the update I haven't been able to start the project for local development and received this error message:

[image: error-message]

I have added that `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to my `.env` file and it works as a temporary workaround but I would like to get rid of it.

This is the main `package.json`:

[image: package.json]

I would like to keep using `eslint@7.5.0` as my main linter but tell `react-scripts` to use `eslint@5.16.0` from its own `node_modules` folder to get rid of that error.

Has anyone encountered this before and found a working solution?

Comment: You're doing exactly what react-scripts is explciitly checking for: you have a different version of ESLint higher in the tree than the one react-scripts has installed. It's not even the usual case where you've mistakenly created a CRA app in a directory that already contained a package, you've done that deliberately. So you have to skip the preflight check, or use the version of ESLint CRA will (which is probably a good idea as then you don't get the risk of different outputs from different linters on the same code).

Comment: Thank you for the quick edit and comment @jonrsharpe!

So every time I update a package, the project won't be able to start if any of the other packages has a different version of the same package as their dependency? Is my best bet to update `react-scripts` to a version that has the same version of ESLint as a dependency that I want to use in my main package.json?

Comment: Again it's something react-scripts checks for, other packages generally don't do that. I'm not certain what you mean by "main package.json" but if you have some structure with a CRA app in a sub-folder of another NPM package then it very rarely plays nicely for this exact reason.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Like I mentioned in the question, I use [yarn workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) so I have multiple package.json files. By "main package.json", I meant the one that's in the project's root folder.

Comment: If anyone else finds this question in the future, the short answer is that I decided not to remove `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` from my `.env` file, because of the dependency hell that updating the `react-scripts` library causes in my project.